# How do I install drivers for ATI X1650 Pro

Tags: 12.04, drivers

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit and I have an ATI X1650 Pro 512mb but there are no drivers for my video card in the restricted drivers. How can I install drivers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the ATI x1650 is no longer supported by AMD/ATI's binary drivers; neither the "restricted" ones nor what you can download off their website.

The last binary driver package supporting this card is [Catalyst 9.3](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Legacy/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx?type=2.4.1&product=2.4.1.3.12&lang=English); you can try downloading and installing it. If it doesn't work (due to kernel changes), sorry, but you're stuck with the default open-source `radeon` driver.

This isn't because of Linux/Ubuntu, but due to AMD/ATI policy; for example, there are no Windows 7 drivers available for the X1650 either!